# Using gdal merge correctly?

Tags: qgis, gdal, landsat

Currently trying to use gdal_merge within qgis to stack three raster bands, the command it's showing is like this:

> gdal_merge.bat -separate -of GTiff -o out.tif "LC80190302014126LGN00_B4.TIF" "LC80190302014126LGN00_B3.TIF" "LC80190302014126LGN00_B2.TIF"

however it keeps giving me ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:out.tif: Permission denied

I realize this should be a fairly simple procedure, is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Message "Permission denied" suggests clearly that you do not have right to write into the default directory what ever it is. Edit the part "-o out.tif" to point to some directory where you can for sure write new files.

Comment: Good, I copied the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"TIFFOpen:out.tif: Permission denied" message means that you do not have enough rights to write a new file into the target directory. Edit the -o parameter to point to some directory where you have write access.